# Win32 support on Windows 10

Tags: winapi, vb6, arm, windows-10

Does Windows 10 support running older Win32 (MFC, ATL, Visual Basic 6) applications on ARM processors? Does it require some form of emulation or conversion?

Comment: No. Emulation: not that I know of. AFAIK you cannot even create desktop applications on a Windows Surface (non x86) computer.

Comment: There was a brief period where you could build your own ARM apps that used the Win32 API (restricted to MS internal and jailbroken tablets). WinRT/Win10 on ARM doesn't support any legacy apps targeting x86. You could potentially run a x86 emulator, but it would have to be built as a "modern" app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no x86 Win32 emulation at all. You need to use a toolset designed for the platform.

Comment: Actually it does have Win32, just *ARM Win32* instead of x86.

Comment: But isn't ARM Win32 just a subset of the Win32 API?

Comment: ARM is a different architecture. It has a completely different ISA. You cannot take x86 code and run  it on  ARM.

Comment: They weren't asking about ARM architecture -- they were asking whether the version of Win32 that works on Windows for ARM architecture is [just] a subset of the Win32 API that Windows has had for years. And by subset they mean functionally, not architecturally -- I think it's pretty obvious the ISAs are different, but that doesn't mean you can't have DLLs and invoke `CreateFile` from your Visual C++ applications.

Comment: @amn Since the ISAs are different, then emulation would be needed to run an x86 executable

Comment: I don't think this is correct anymore. Microsoft has allowed running of x86 apps under Windows 10 ARM for a while now and are working on allowing 64 bit apps as well.  See [The Surface Pro X can finally run all Windows apps](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/microsoft-surface-pro-x-finally-run-windows-apps/) as well as [Microsoft goes all-in on Windows 10 on ARM, with its target set on the M1 Mac](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/microsoft-goes-all-in-on-arm-build-2021/). I've been tested a simple MFC application targeting ARM64 with VS 2019 using an x86 installer engine, NSIS.

Answer (score 0):

As with 7/8.1 Windows has leaned further and further into the Net way of doing things. So many of the commandline functions are done through net calls.

Also note that Win10 is pretty much Win NT, it is basically what Win98 should have been, to save us the disasterous influx of virus's on what was an OS with a swing door and no form of protection.

That NT side of things will affect all programmers in time, particularly over the following,

The rights of your users. This is a good thing because we have all been frustrated at our users leaving the doors open for virus and hacking. NT at least helps elliminate a lot of that.

File handling. Win10 is a big step closer to an OS on demand (Which is Microsoft's current target), so we can not assume items that our software makes use of will always be locally present, so we must go through the .NET route ready for when ondemand comes in properly so that the OS will handle the demands for us. Though it does worry me that we currently have no real clues as to how that will be handled if the request can not be full filled.

But also we can not be lazy with file access rights. For example we tend to make assumptions in the user's area about access rights, then get bitten in the bum when we do a scan or search of all directories, only to find DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories is unuseable unless we make sure special folders will not stop it part way through.

Since all directories will in time be special folders, we need to be handling the access rights on the work we do now. More easily done in C++ than C# im my opinion.

So, if you have done it in 'Managed' code then it ought to go anywhere that C# and VB go, call my synical if you like, but I can not help but have doubts about that, I can not really see MS finding it desirable to have on-demand applications and OS on NET but also providing Win32 wrapped in MFC running as an alternative. You may find your code is trapped in a shrinking box.