# Availability of the Snapdragon Development Kit for Windows ARM

Tags: sdk, windows-10, arm, qualcomm

Microsoft and Qualcomm announced a new Snapdragon Developer Kit to be released this summer, 2021. Where can I find this kit? Has it been released yet?

I'm not asking for a recommendation for software. I'm asking where is this kit sold. Everything I've found indicates the Microsoft Store but I can't find it there. Qualcomm has several different Snapdragon development kits offered through various retailers but none of those are the Snapdragon Developer kit for Windows ARM. Nor does a Google search bring up anything other than either press releases or other bits of internet flotsam that is not related to this question.

[Microsoft goes all-in on Windows 10 on ARM, with its target set on the M1 Macs](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/microsoft-goes-all-in-on-arm-build-2021/)

> The forefront of those plans is a new Snapdragon Developer Kit.
> Microsoft says that this kit is an affordable Windows on ARM-based PC
> that is specially designed for developers. The kit will be available
> for purchase at the Microsoft Store this summer as part of a
> partnership between Microsoft and Qualcomm Technologies. Microsoft
> didn’t share specific pricing or availability, but notes it will be
> “cost-effective.”

[Windows on Snapdragon](https://developer.qualcomm.com/hardware/windows-on-snapdragon) provides a brief press release on the kit with a description but no way to buy it that I can see.

[Qualcomm Enhances Support for Developers with New Snapdragon Developer Kit for Windows 10 on Arm PCs](https://www.qualcomm.com/news/releases/2021/05/24/qualcomm-enhances-support-developers-new-snapdragon-developer-kit-windows) also mentions the kit but no details about where or how to purchase.

Or is there some other way of obtaining an inexpensive Windows Arm system for less than US$200?

Currently I'm planning to go with Windows 10 ARM Preview Build on a Raspberry Pi 4 and have just heard of the Snapdragon Development kit.

[How to install Windows 10 on Raspberry Pi 4](https://www.windowslatest.com/2020/07/24/install-windows-10-on-raspberry-pi/)

[How to Install Windows 10 on Raspberry Pi? (Illustrated Guide)](https://raspberrytips.com/install-windows10-raspberry-pi/)

[Booting my Raspberry Pi 4 from a USB device](https://www.zdnet.com/article/booting-my-raspberry-pi-4-from-a-usb-device/)

Comment: I've been searching for info on it every week since it was announced. As far as I know, it just has not been officially released yet. There aren't many days of summer left, so it should be soon if it isn't delayed.

Comment: @LB-- Thanks for your note. I went ahead with the preview Windows 10 ARM for Raspberry Pi 4 on a Raspberry Pi 4 approach and that seems to be working thus far with a simple MFC application. I've documented that approach with this answer I posted to an earlier, more general question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69079582/1466970

Comment: @RichardChambers https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/d/ecs-liva-mini-box-qc710-desktop/8z247h1h3skp?activetab=pivot:overviewtab ($219)

Comment: @KuboTakehiro Thanks! Could you provide this as an answer to the post? This is interesting, "Note: There are no refunds available on this product. This product is meant for developers, not consumers." The Tech specs look good, And looks like Windows 11 will be available for it as well. See also https://www.xda-developers.com/qualcomms-snapdragon-developer-kit-for-219/

Comment: Somehow Microsoft only sells this to U.S. residents. How can developers outside the U.S. purchase the Snapdragon Development Kit for Windows ARM?

Comment: @BrechtSanders According to this Dec 2021 article, https://www.qualcomm.com/news/onq/2021/12/20/snapdragon-developer-kit-now-available-testing-windows-apps-arm  it's "currently U.S. sales only" which implies that outside the U.S. is coming. The article doesn't say why U.S. only nor could I find anything about export restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Snapdragon Developer Kit for Windows on ARM was available for purchase from the Microsoft Store:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/d/ecs-liva-mini-box-qc710-desktop/8z247h1h3skp

However, it's no longer available, since Microsoft has now launched the Windows Dev Kit 2023 to replace it:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/d/windows-dev-kit-2023/94k0p67w7581

This device uses the Snapdragon® 8cx Gen 3 compute platform, a considerable upgrade over the Snapdragon 7c in the earlier Snapdragon Development Kit. It is intended to be used as a development machine, and I can personally confirm it works well as one with the ARM64 native version of Visual Studio 2022.

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/dev-kit/